# We have two tails and 3 heads. Find the number of ways in which 2 heads are placed adjacent to each other?

Tags: combinations

I tried the most ubiquitous taught way. Bundle two heads together {HH}. Now, we have H,{HH},T,T. We have $\frac{4!}{2!}$ combinations if we consider H and {HH} distinct. So in the previous calculation H{HH}TT and {HH}HTT are both counted (and considered different). Basically 3 consecutive heads are counted twice. To arrive at the correct answer, I subtract the cases when 3 heads are consecutive. The final answer will be

$ \frac{4!}{2!}-\frac{3!}{2!} = 9 $

I wanted to ask if there is a general way to solve such problems. For example, the problem would be much difficult if we had 10 heads and 5 tails, and we want to enumerate the items in which there are at least 3 consecutive heads.

Comment: The problem is not clear.  Are you just saying, "find the number of arrangements in which there are at least two consecutive Heads"?  If so...well, the only bad arrangement is $HTHTH$.

Comment: I think it is clarified in the statement and the solution is given. The purpose is more geared towards a generalized approach of solving such issues.

Comment: I couldn't follow your solution, it seems unnecessarily complicated.  For a general situation, consider the lists of the form $T^{a_1}HT^{a_2}H\cdots HT^{a_{N+1}}$  (assuming you have $N$ Heads).  Where $\sum a_i= M$ (if you have $M$ Tails) and $a_2, \cdots, a_{N}$ are all strictly positive.  Counting these is a routine Stars and Bars problem.  Then just subtract from the unrestricted arrangements.